# Does Ruby or Rails have a function named getaddrinfo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does Ruby or Rails have a function named `getaddrinfo`?

If so, where is its source found?

Comment: Why there is down vote? I'm getting `SocketError getaddrinfo: No such host is known.` but i can't find this function anywhere

Comment: In that case the host for the web address you are trying to reach is not available. If you are doing a `require 'open-uri'; open(some_url)` then do a `puts some_url` to see what you are actually trying to get - chances are you've got a bad url.

Comment: Actually I was trying to send email with RoR actionmailer, see this question too http://stackoverflow.com/q/4582759/174261

Comment: I gave you the downvote. You can find the answer to your question by clicking on the top answer when you search for "ruby getaddrinfo". You could try to make the smallest bit of work before asking a question. I've voted to close your question too.

Comment: If you just went so far as to type "ruby geta" into Google the first suggestion for a search is "ruby getaddrinfo". The very first hit is for documentation on the Socket class and this method. I give you another downvote. Stack Overflow should not be used as a substitute for basic searching.

Comment: "...but i can't find this function anywhere". I hardly believe that. Even `ri` which is installed with Ruby on your machine, knows about `getaddrinfo`.

Comment: Likewise, downvoted for all the reasons given above. At least *attempt* to find something out before posting a question on SO. It will help you as you will learn more, and it will help SO by improving the average quality of the questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getaddrinfo` is part of the Socket class.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/socket/rdoc/classes/Socket.html#M003737

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers have said, `getaddrinfo` is part of the Socket class.

The error you're seeing happens when your Domain Name Service (AKA "DNS") resolver on your machine can not find the host you've asked it to find.

That can happen for multiple reasons. I've had it happen when the name I'm looking for is spelled wrong, when the DNS is down, when the DNS is wrong/misconfigured.

You can try triangulating the problem by dropping to the command-line and typing one or more of:

```
host name_of_the_host
dig name_of_the_host
whois name_of_the_host
```

Alternately, you can use the "Network Utility" if you're on a Mac, and use the "Lookup" tab. If any of those solutions respond with a successful hit then you have a problem in your Ruby setup, but it's very likely you'll get a similar response from those tools. In that case it's pointing to the problem being upstream from your computer, in whatever box your computer gets its name resolution from. Or, again, that the host you're requesting isn't actually known by that name.

Mail can do that when the mail-relay information isn't correct. Once mail leaves that machine you usually won't get a notice unless the message can't be forwarded, but that takes a while to time out and bounce back.

Comment: I'm using Win7 and I'm getting proper response from `ping` and `tracert`

Comment: Ping and traceroute are not guarantees that the host is alive, though they do give evidence that routing is working.

Answer (score 2):

`getaddrinfo()` is a part of the POSIX standard API, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo